# how to get value with symbol from google api for currency converter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, currency-exchange-rates

I need to convert currency from `INR` to `other`. I did this by google currency conveter, but I got an html value, I only need the value with the symbol.

I don't want it to be converted in html value because I need it to pass the data in my payment gateway.

My ajax controller for fetching data:

```
<script>
var currency_url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>products/change_currency/"
function changeCurrency(currency_value){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url :currency_url,
        data:{to:currency_value,amount:<?php echo $total_amount;  ?>},
        success:function(data){
            //alert(JSON.parse(data));
            //$('#cuur').html(data);
            alert(data);
        }

    });

}
</script>
```

PHP CodeIgniter Controller:

```
public function change_currency()
{

    $from = 'INR';
    $to = $this->input->post('to');
    $amount = $this->input->post('amount');

    $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to"; 

    $req = curl_init();

    $timeout = 0; 
    curl_setopt ($req, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt ($req, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); 
    curl_setopt ($req, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
    $rawdata = curl_exec($req);


    $data = explode('bld>', $rawdata);
    $data = explode($to, $data[1]);
    $value = round($data[0], 2);
    echo $value;
    exit;

}
```

Current Output:

```
555.00
5888.00
4343.00
```

And I need if I pass `INR` to `$`

then value should come in `$525.00`